# Get metadata of files in Sharepoint website folder and set the metadata of copied files (from SharePoint) in blob storage accordingly in ADF pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-functions, cloud, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am creating an Azure Data Factory pipeline and in that need to attach the metadata of files in SharePoint folder (which I am copying to Azure blob storage) to the respective blobs.

I have successfully implemented an Azure Data Factory pipeline using the guide titled
[Copy files from SharePoint to Blob Storage using Azure Data Factory](https://www.syntera.ch/blog/2022/10/10/copy-files-from-sharepoint-to-blob-storage-using-azure-data-factory/)

On a high level this pipeline copies files from a SharePoint website folder to Azure Blob Storage using Azure Data Factory.

Now, I am seeking assistance on how to integrate a new functionality into the existing pipeline. Specifically, I need to retrieve the metadata of files (e.g., file_name, file_size, file_path, last_modified, date_created) from the SharePoint website folder and then append this metadata to the respective blobs that are copied in Azure Blob Storage during the pipeline execution.

Could anyone kindly suggest some approaches or ideas to achieve this seamless integration of file metadata from SharePoint to Azure Blob Storage using Azure Data Factory? Any guidance or code snippets would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your valuable input!